# NGINX Docker on Server with pre-existing NGINX on Ubuntu Server

Tags: django, docker, ubuntu, nginx, docker-compose

I am currently running into an issue with one of my projects that will be running in Docker on my Ubuntu Server with a NGINX docker container to manage the reverse proxy for the Django Project. My issue I am running into is I already have previous Django projects running on that particular Ubuntu server so port 80 is already being used by a NGINX block running on the actual server.

Is there a workaround to running my Docker NGINX as well as the Ubuntu NGINX and have my docker image run as a "add on" site because the Django sites hosted there are clients websites, so I would prefer to not interfere with them if I dont have to.

My project needs HTTPS because it is serving data to a React-Native app running on Android APK 28 which for some reason has a security rule that blocks non HTTPS connections from happening in the app. If anyone else has run into an issue like this I would gladly appreciate the advice on how to tackle this issue.

I have tried running NGINX in Docker with port 81 instead of port 80 and that works perfectly, but I dont think there is a way to make a secure connection to port 81 is there?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just mess with default HTTP ports for endpoints - user browsers use 80 and 443 by default. If you change those, your users would have to connect to `your.server.com:81` or something similar. Nobody would do that for a public server, but this can be an option for a private one.

I think a reasonable way out of this will be to use host's NGINX to proxy requests into Docker's NGINX (if there is sense in keeping it at all). You can handle HTTPS termination on host's NGINX and pass plain HTTP into Docker's one.

Another adequate option is to use another server, so that everything works with no dirty hacking involved.

Comment: Running a port number with the URL should be fine because the Django app running on Docker is the backend for the React-Native app. So users shouldn't be browsing the Django app, only receiving data from it through the React-Native app

Comment: If so then you can use any port, it's just a number.

Comment: @Blademaster680  Just replace `listen 443 ssl;` with something like `listen 2443 ssl;` and adjust links in your app if necessary. That's it.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks for your input, been thinking about this issue for the past 2 days in the back of my mind lol.